# PHP : Is there a way, to write this if/elseif/else statement shorter?

Tags: php, if-statement

So I have been actively learning PHP for the past days and, for practise, I wrote PHP script, which takes HTML Form values.

I tried writing script, where I have 5 persons, and you have to input your name and last name. If it matches with one of the five persons, it sends one message, if not, other. Here it is (Without form part, only PHP):

```
    $first = $_POST["first"];
    $last = $_POST["last"];

    if ($first == "Jeb") {
        if ($last == "Jeb") {
            print "Hello!";
        } else {
            print "I dont know you!";
        }
    } elseif ($first == "Bob") {
        if ($last == "Bob") {
            print "Hello!";
        } else {
            print "I dont know you!";
        }
    } elseif ($first == "Bill") {
        if ($last == "Bill") {
            print "Hello!";
        } else {
            print "I dont know you!";
        }
    } elseif ($first == "Annie") {
        if ($last == "Annie") {
            print "Hello!";
        } else {
            print "I dont know you!";
        }
    } elseif ($first == "Hugo") {
        if ($last == "Hugo") {
            print "Hello!";
        } else {
            print "I dont know you!";
        }
    } else {
        print "I dont know you!";
    }
```

It works great, but I have question- can this be done easier / written shorter? And can this be done using switch statement?

Any respone will be apprecieted!

Comment: there is a function called switch* - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: i can see a way using arrays also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i can see a way using arrays

```
$people=array('Bob Bob', 'Bill Bill');//etc

if(in_array($first.' '.$last,$people)){
 print "Hello!";
}else{
   print "I dont know you!";
}
```

Comment: I think your solution is better because it has a flexibility of being able to add names where the first and last aren't equal.

Comment: I suspect that was just example names.

Comment: @Fred-ii- im pretty too (mommy told me so)

Comment: Tried every single answer, your's seems the most simplest one. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A solution using arrays. Assumes all known names are pairs of the same name (bob bob, jeb jeb, etc)

```
$knownNames = array("Jeb", "Bob", "Bill", "Annie", "Hugo");
if (in_array($first, $knownNames) && $first == $last)
  print "Hello!";
else
  print "I don't know you!"
```

Comment: unlikely that the people really have first and last names the same, expect that was just an example

Comment: Most likely, but this question is clearly contrived. I can't imagine a scenario in a real environment where you'll be working with a hard-coded list of names like this.

Comment: I'm no longer surprised by some peoples real code environments :) And i would guess "homework" here. Any good teach would point out this flaw also

Comment: Hopefully he goes with something more like yours, oofda. I'm shocked this was accepted lol

Answer (score 0):

I'd use arrays instead (avoids duplicating code/ifs)

```
$name = array(
  'first' => $_POST["first"],
  'last'  => $_POST["last"]
);

$knownNames = array(
  array(
    'first' => 'Bob',
    'last'  => 'Bob'
  ),
  array(
    'first' => 'Bill',
    'last'  => 'Bill'
  ),
  array(
    'first' => 'Annie',
    'last'  => 'Annie'
  ),
  array(
    'first' => 'Hugo',
    'last'  => 'Hugo'
  )
);

if (in_array($name, $knownNames)) {
    print "Hello!";
} else {
    print "I dont know you!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are making a decision based on two tests:

Do I recognize the submitted first name?

Do I recognize the submitted last name?

Then you are responding based on whether the above tests are BOTH true.

I would suggest that you separate each test into it's own function:

```
    function isValidFirstName($name)
    {
        $valid_names = array('Jeb','Bob','Bill','Annie','Hugo');
        return in_array($name, $valid_names);
    }

    function isValidLastName($name)
    {
        $valid_names = array('Jeb','Bob','Bill','Annie','Hugo');
        return in_array($name, $valid_names);
    }

    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $last = $_POST['last'];

    if( isValidFirstName($first) && isValidLastName($last) )
    {
        print "Hello!";
    } else 
    {
        print "I don't know you!";
    }
```

Comment: but **Bill Bob** is not known, but would be in your code